# Server 2012R2 running EXE in CGI

Tags: iis, windows-server-2012-r2

We are upgrading our Windows Server 2003 to Windows Server 2012 R2.
We run multiple websites that run binary executables for CGI,
so `mywebsite.com/cgi/program.exe` should run `program.exe`.

Right now, the EXE file *downloads* instead of running. 
There are thousands of programs, so I want to allow them all, not one at a time.

How do I achieve that?

Comment: I've found that if I append "www" (e.g.:  **www**.mywebsite.com/cgi/program.exe) it works.